# How to print line number for the root cause of memory leak using valgrind 3.7.0?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

The output format is displaying stack so its hard to find the root cause.

```
 ==21663== Invalid read of size 4
==21663==    at 0x4448117: iurcall_init_rlmgt_IsAllAlcapSuccess(Iurcall_Init_CallCtx_t*) (iurcall_init_rlmgt_p.cc:6319)
==21663==    by 0x47D98DD: iurcall_init_rlmgt_IsAllAlcapSuccess_Test_return_1_when_edchMacD_flow_ctx_not_exist_and_alcapEstablish_is_FALSE_Test::TestBody() (iurcall_init_rlmgt_p_test.cc:373)
==21663==    by 0x8BCAB27: testing::Test::Run() (gmock-gtest-all.cc:3436)
==21663==    by 0x8BD1966: testing::internal::TestInfoImpl::Run() (gmock-gtest-all.cc:3655)
==21663==    by 0x8BD1AA8: testing::TestCase::Run() (gmock-gtest-all.cc:3761)
==21663==    by 0x8BD1D96: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gmock-gtest-all.cc:5365)
==21663==    by 0x8BD1F21: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gmock-gtest-all.cc:5028)
==21663==    by 0x4820149: Gtest_initialisation(int, char**) (iurcall_init_gtest_main.cc:49)
==21663==    by 0x808E500: main (bosinit_config_template.h:439)
==21663==  Address 0xa8190e4 is 44 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
```

Comment: This is not a memory leak, it is an invalid read error.You are writing beyond the bounds of allocated memory.Valgrind shows you the call stack with line numbers `(iurcall_init_gtest_main.cc:49)` <---- `49` is the line number.

Answer (score 0):

This Valgrind output looks incomplete. It should be something like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9891767/72178) where  the second call stack is printed after `Address 0xa8190e4 is 44 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd`.

This call stack is the root cause of the problem. It is not a memory leak. You are trying to work with already deallocated object. The second call stack is where the object was deallocated and the first one is where it was used.